# styling of fake cursor

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I'm  trying to create fake input and emulate its behaviour.  input  will be div element and each  character in it span element.  here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dfv9u99v/15/)

here is  the problem - when I'm  inserting my "cursor" after elment its visually  kind of sticking to the next  element. If I  remove width property from "mock-cursor" - text  is jumping. I  would like "cursor" to  be positioned in  the center between  two  characters. but I'm not sure how to  achieve this.

code is also  available here

```
 //html

<div id="inputEmulation">
  <div id='mock-cursor'>|</div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>0</span>
 </div>
 <button id = "moveCursor">Move  cursor</button>
```

Now i need to  emulate cursor move between the characters

here is styling and simple javascript code for demonstration.  this is what I've got so  far

```
//javascirpt
     var cursor = "<div id='mock-cursor'>|</div>",
     i = 0;

    $("#moveCursor").click(function(){
        if(i<10){
            $("#mock-cursor").remove();
            $(cursor).insertAfter($("#inputEmulation span")[i])
            i++;
        }
    })


//css
#inputEmulation{
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,176,235,0.8);
    border-radius:6px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    background:rgba(10,150,197,0.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align:left;

}
#inputEmulation span{
    margin: 10px 0px;
}


#mock-cursor {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
    animation: blink 1s infinite;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight:  lighter;
    width:0;
}


@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0%, 49.9%, 100%   { opacity: 0; }
    50%, 99.9% { opacity: 1; }
}


button {
    display:block
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: The first question to ask is why do you need this? Why not just used a standard `input` styled as you need and let the browser chrome control low-level functions such as cursor position?

Comment: Agree with @RoryMcCrossan. Just... why are you doing this...?

Comment: You can add, to the `#mock-cursor` something like `position: relative; right:3px`, then it will be more centered.

Comment: Well,  I  understand  it might  seem odd.  But I'm  creating virtual  keyboard where  focus  has always to  be on  "virtual  keys" and at the same time I  need  visual indication in input where characters are being typed (also focus). As there cant be double focus on  a  page, I came up  with the idea that I  can  use real  but hidden  input for all the operations and then just mirror all the changes in a fake one. So basically the input happens  in  real but hidden input.  I get it content, count where  cursor should be  located and display that in my  fake input. Hope, this  makes some sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomek provided the quick answer to you question is in his comment.

To make it look more like a real cursor, make it thinner and make it higher than the text.
Check out this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfv9u99v/16/).
It also uses `position:absolute` so you can use the `width`-attribute without a problem.

Comment: thanks, that's  very good that  we've got rid of that  extra "|" character.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is a pretty zany idea,(especially if you're going for full input emulation) but hey, why not.

In my opinion a 1px border looks better as a caret. Since you're inserting the element in between the characters, you can use the next-sibling selector to offset the width of the caret, like:

```
#mock-cursor + span{
   margin-left: -1px; //caret-width
}
```

here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/huu2a9gx/1/